# Adding x509v3 extension causes Mozilla pkix not to trust

Tags: c++, firefox, ssl, certificate, mozilla

I'm adding a self-signed root cert via the NSS/NSPR C++ API.

This needs one x509v3 extension, the subject alt name.  However, adding this extension, or any x509v3 extension, causes firefox to fail with `Error code: sec_error_extension_value_invalid`.

```cpp
// Add subjectAltName x509v3 extension containing our localhost IPv4
// address of 127.0.0.1.  The subjectAltName entry takes precedence over
// the CommonName (CN) entry, thus we are allowed to have a more
// descriptive name there. In addition, this is needed by Safari on Mac in
// order to properly trust the certificate.
X509V3_CTX ctx;
X509V3_set_ctx_nodb(&ctx);
X509V3_set_ctx(&ctx, m_x509, m_x509, nullptr, nullptr, 0);

// Removing this line causes the cert to be accepted by firefox:
X509_EXTENSION* ext = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(nullptr, &ctx, NID_subject_alt_name, (char*)"DNS:127.0.0.1,IP:127.0.0.1");

if (ext) {
  X509_add_ext(m_x509, ext , -1);
  X509_EXTENSION_free(ext);
}

// Sign the certificate
X509_sign(m_x509, m_key->m_pkey, EVP_sha1());
```

This appears to be a pkix bug, as setting `use_mozillapkix_verification = false`  in `about:config`, or using ff < 31, causes the cert to be accepted OK.

Is this a pkix bug? Or are there something overlooked here?

Answer (score 3):

via https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1045973

> NSS accepts v1/v2 ceritificates with v3 extensions, mozilla::pkix does not

The fix:

```
X509_set_version(m_x509, 2L);
```

Answer (score 2):

This bug is [filed at bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1045973), so people looking for an answer may want to check the bug's comments.